# Proper use of TcpClient in U3d

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I've been working long and hard on a server that works wonderfully with all of my projects created in Java, and I've been struggling with creating a C# port that will work with Unity3D. I've finally got it working however, but I'm trying to find the proper way to handle networking inside of Unity.

Unity does not play well with multiple threads. It's like a single child that doesn't want a brother/sister. However, due to my Java practices of handling networking/rendering on seperate threads, I managed to find a way to use a seperate thread for networking in Unity- The problem with doing this is that Unity will not allow any logical(Unity based) calls from other threads, so instead I have to create a `Queue<Delegate>` which stores a bunch of delegate methods to be executed in the Unity update loop.

I've been told that this is a bad practice, but I have not been presented with a better one. I'm looking for answers such as "why this is better", and not opinionated statements. Running TcpClient logic inside of the Update() function blocks the thread and causes unity to crash. Should I be using an coroutine? If so, why?

Comment: Presumably, the point of adding networking to your program is to allow data to move from and to your program's main logic. I don't know much about Unity, but I assume the cross-thread limitation is similar to that found in other UI frameworks, and that you simply can't access framework objects from other threads. I.e. threads in general aren't prohibited. So while a `Queue<Action>` seems reasonable, it might be overkill. Why not just have producer/consumer logic in each direction to move _data_ to and from your main program code, so that it can act on it?

Comment: @Peter - Could you elaborate a little? I'm not sure I understand the structure you're talking about with `logic in each direction to move data to and from your main program code` - This was the only reason I was using `Queue<Action>`, could you elaborate so I can get a better understanding? Client's aren't really my forte.

Comment: Consider how you would have done it simply single-threaded: you'd receive some data, then act on it. You can't do it that way because waiting to receive data would block your main program until data came it. But you _can_ receive that data in a different thread, and put the _data_ in a queue that the main thread can check at an appropriate time (or times, depending on design) and act on it if it's there, proceeding past that point if it's not. That said, your current queue is probably fine too if it works; I just suggested the alternative as a possible simplification.

Comment: @Peter - I feel like I'm being dense, as it seems like the two designs are identical. Are you just suggesting flag-checking instead of cycling through data in order? Considering in my application the `appropriate time` is as soon as possible, looping through the `Queue<>` and calling `Dequeue()()` as fast as possible is probably the best solution, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the phrase "flag-checking". The two options are similar, but certainly not _identical_. In one case, you are executing arbitrary methods; in the other, you have a specific type of processing, applied only to data objects (i.e. constructed from data received in a different thread). Frankly, it surprises me that given the thread-affinity in Unity, it doesn't already have a built-in mechanism for invoking arbitrary delegate instances on its single "main" thread. Anyway, it sounds to me like you have something that works, so sticking with that seems fine.